# Copying or visiting the same tree multiple times?

Tags: antlr4

I have a program that does multiple analyses on the same AST, one analysis per thread. The analysis is done with a Visitor. For now, each thread parses the program input, transforms it as an AST, and runs its visitor. However, this is very time-consuming to parse the same program multiple times.

I tried to parse the program once and have the threads to use the visitors, but it does not seem multiple visitors can share the same tree (especially concurrently).

One alternative would be to parse the program, build the AST and make a copy of the AST that is later analyzed.

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

1. Is there any way to safely process the same AST by different threads?
2. Is there a way to make a copy (e.g. deepcopy) of an AST?

Comment: Sharing the parse tree or the AST is no problem, as long as you do only reads or protect sections where the tree is modified with a thread lock. However, it makes not much sense to change the tree while other visitors are walking over it.

Comment: @MikeLischke when I share the tree with my visitor, a lot of analysis is no longer working. I guess there are some data mutated while walking the tree.